# How to open another link in new tab with same popup button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button, popup

I'm using a button to open a ajax html popup, with the same button on click I want to open another page in new tab...any help appreciated

Here's html code I'm using

```
<a href="test.html" class="ajax-popup-link"><button type="button" style="background:green;float:right;">Activate</button></a>
```

Here's the javascript function

```
<script src="../assets/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
 closeOnContentClick: false
});
});</script>
```

Comment: Can you simply use `window.open()` as many times as you want?

Comment: If I'm usin window.open() the popup is not opening

Comment: you wanted to open the link in the new tab, right?

Comment: I am using a button to open popup with that same button i want open another page on same click

Answer (score 1):

Add another event to it:

```
$('.ajax-popup-link').click(function(){
     window.open("/some-link.html"); // you can pass options
});
```

Comment: hey buddy plz could you guide me its working but there is a issue i have several buttons placed in a page  and i want to open different links from each button

Comment: Add URL in data-href attribute associated with each button and on click open the respective link. `$(".link-button").click(function (){ window.open($(this).data("href"); });`